# Refresh variable value each loop

Tags: php, excel, loops, object, phpexcel

I have a trouble, when I upload multiple Excel files in PHP. I am using a `for` loop to get data in a specific cell in each file, but I'm getting the same value as the first file's value. It doesn't get me value for each file instead it just stuck on the first value.

I was trying to get Value form cell 'N14' in each file.

```
<?php
include 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


$total=count($_FILES['files']['name']);
for($x=0;$x<$total;$x++){
    $file = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$x];
    $fileName = $_FILES['files']['name'][$x];
    $load = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);
    $num=$load->getSheetCount() ;

    echo $fileName."    ";

    $sheets =$load->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $sheets = $load->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

    $i = 1;
    foreach ($sheets as $sheet) {
        $c=$sheet['N'];
        if($i==14){echo $c."</br>";break;}

        $i++;
    }   
}
```

Output :

```
proses 15 Januari 2017.xlsx **308060**

proses 16 Januari 2017.xlsx **308060**

proses 17 Januari 2017.xlsx **308060**
```

can someone explain to me why it repeat the value from the first one?

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys, that's really helpful. but it doesn't solve my problem so use the hard way. it's not like your answer is wrong but it just didn't work for me.. anyway i'm really happy that's someone answering my question. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sheets have a name (say "sheetName") you could try:

```
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");
$excelWorkbook = $reader->load($file);
$sheet = $excelWorkbook->getSheetByName("sheetName");
$c= $sheet->getCell("N14")->getValue();
```

This might make a simpler starting point.

Comment: I've used that method but it returns   the formula, not the value \n                                           
proses1.xlsx : =SUM(N9:N12)\n
proses1.xlsx : =SUM(N9:N12)\n
proses1.xlsx : =SUM(N9:N13)

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to [get the cell value directly](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/accessing-cells/#retrieving-a-cell-value-by-coordinate):

```
<?php
include 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


$total = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

for($x = 0; $x < $total; $x++) {
    $file     = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$x];
    $fileName = $_FILES['files']['name'][$x];
    $load     = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file);

    $sheet = $load->getSheet(0);
    $i = $sheet->getCell("N14")->getCalculatedValue();

    echo "$fileName : $i<br/>";
}
```

As to why your original code wasn't working, it's hard to say without knowing the files involved. It looks like it should work, as long as the files all have different values. But it is very inefficient to load the Excel file into an array (the library already has a copy in memory, and then you make another one) and then to loop through the first 14 rows for no reason.

Comment: I've used that method but it returns   the formula, not the value  ................                                               
proses1.xlsx : =SUM(N9:N12)
proses1.xlsx : =SUM(N9:N12)
proses1.xlsx : =SUM(N9:N13)

Comment: I have try it and none of them work, and then i found another way to solve my problem with excel and cmd.. anyway thanks for answering my question that's really saving me..